# ASP.NET web application for mobile browsers - any issue with Hidden fields?

Tags: asp.net, html, postback, hidden-field

I am wondering if some mobile browsers are not able to handle the html hidden fields properly. (i.e. fails to pass the value on submitting the form)

If that is the case then is it safe to assume that the browser will not able able to browse through ASP.NET pages with postbacks as postback uses hidden fields?

Thanks in advance.

Felix

Comment: So, have you at least tried it?

Comment: Where are you getting the idea that mobile browsers do not support hidden fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK this is not an issue as the recommendation from Microsoft is to switch to normal ASP.NET controls. Actually, even the `System.Web.Mobile.dll` assembly [is being deprecated](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/add-mobile-pages-to-your-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-application).

Comment: Thanks for the information. Do you know what happens if hidden field is not supported by a browser? ASP.NET would not work?

Comment: @user1012002 all mobile browsers support hidden fields; asp.net will work.

Comment: I guess that is what I wanted to hear. Thanks a lot! :)